# is it possible to get 0 accuracy after normalization?

Tags: neural-network

I created a neural network with 4 hidden layers and used ReLU as the activation function for them, and an output layer with softmax. when I fed this neural network with a dataset I got some accuracy from the predictions it produced but when I normalized the same data using:

```
nx= (X - mean(X)) / stdev(X)
```

the accuracy of the produced predictions was zero?!!
why did that happen? any ideas!

I used this simple block:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(hidden_size, input_dim=input_size, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer='sgd',   metrics=['accuracy'])
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Test \n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot brackets (X-mean(X))/std(X), but more likely its some floating point int issue, My bet would be that you're feeding it with a zero vector (nx==0) or something of that sort

Comment: no, I even denormalized the dataset and it worked ( I mean the normalized one), I know about the brackets, everything about the normalization is right! and I just added the brackets as they are in the real code.

Comment: I don't think a four layer neural net can have problems to work a linear transform into the model. How are you initializing the weights?

Comment: just like any weights initializing! I don't know what you mean exactly!

Comment: I am using keras with tensorflow as backend.

Comment: Can you add the layers building code to your question?

Comment: And you say you had some accuracy (what was it BTW and how many classes?) and now 0 (is this approximately or an actual zero?). I could possibly think of a way to generate synthetic data that will behave thus but for a naturally occurring one I find this extremely unlikely.

Could you try maybe adding kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='random_normal' just to see what happens?

Comment: 2 classes, and yes actual zero. the accuracy before normalization is 18.10%

Comment: 2 classes and 1 neutral or just 2 classes? you do know that random has a 50% accuracy

Comment: just have one out neuron in the output layer ( just one class sorry )

Comment: Thanks man, I guess my data is dirty, just looked at it closely to find a lot of similar inputs give different outputs or different inputs give same outputs, that's insane, right? sorry for disturbing "Happy New Year"

Comment: Same inputs giving different outputs and vice verse should still let the network exceed 50% unless it's the whole dataset, I'd play with the activation functions and other knobs and see what happens. but sure, if you wanna switch data that's legit.

I'm a Jewish atheist so happy Christ's bris to you too :)

Comment: I need to write a script to make sure of my dataset plus I am playing with the activation functions and the optimizers to see. but still, when I normalize the data I get zero accuracy! so I stopped normalizing it